# React - Replacing a component with another on button click

Tags: reactjs

I've two React components, I want a button click in one to replace it entirely with the second.

This is my App Component:

```
const App = () =>{

    const[showMarketing, setShowMarketing] = useState(false);
    const[showLanding, setShowLanding] = useState(true)

    const toggleViews = () =>{
        setShowMarketing(!showMarketing);
        setShowLanding(!showLanding);
    }

  return (
      <div>
        {showMarketing && <Marketing/>} {showLanding && <Landing toggleViewFn={toggleViews}/> }
      </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

This is the Component that is rendered by default:

```
const Landing = ({toggleViewFn}) =>(
    <div className="shrink-wrapper">
        <header className="small-vertical">
            <figure className="logo">
                <a href="">
                    <img src={logo} onClick={() => toggleViewFn()}/>
                </a>
            </figure>
            <nav>

            </nav>
        </header>
    </div>
    );
```

This is the component that I want to render on the img click:

```
const Marketing = () => (
    <div>
      ......Something here
    </div>

);
```

In the current code, the switch happens for a second and the the UI is back to the Landing component. I can't seem to understand why?
I'm new to React, any help appreciated.

Comment: You can simplify this by using only one boolean flag.

Comment: The problem is that your `<img/>` with the `onClick` is wrapped with an anchor-- when you click the `<img/>`, the click handler is fired but the anchor click is also registered and the browser navigates.  Ultimately, if you are trying to use this for routing, you'd be better off leveraging a library like React Router-- anchors with empty hrefs are usually a problem for accessibility purposes.  I suspect if you remove the wrapping `<a>` this will work as expected.

Comment: @AlexanderNied You should post this as an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @AlexanderNied Indeed this works. Thanks a ton, if you post this as an answer, I can totally accept this.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice--  Yes, I only didn't bc I suspected that it was probably a duplicate, but on a quick search I only found similar posts relating to using a `<button/>`, so I will probably do that; thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `<img/>` with the `onClick` is wrapped with an anchor-- when you click the `<img/>`, the click handler is fired but the anchor click is also registered and the browser navigates. I suspect if you remove the wrapping `<a>` this will work as expected.

Ultimately, if you are trying to use this for routing, you'd be better off leveraging a library like [React Router](https://reactrouter.com/); while you *could* try to manage your own routing on your own, it can be complex and is rife with accessibility pitfalls (for instance, using anchors with empty `href`s to wrap items with `onClick` handlers is not particularly accessible).  Hope this helps.

Comment: Probably more of a CSS question - is there a way I can still continue to use the a tag?

Comment: @TannishaHill - Yeah-- libraries like React Router do that for you-- they render an anchor and then hijack it to prevent the browser from actually refreshing and route internally in the app instead.  You could _probably_ manage this yourself by putting the `onClick` on the anchor itself, [preventing the default anchor action of navigating](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault), and then doing your routing w/ React.  I don't know that that is how React Router does it but that's my hunch. You'd also need to manually update the URL (if desired). Hope this helps :)